# Unable to create a new division with a name from a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
var current = "current" + String(c)
$('<div id = current > </div>').appendTo('body');
var stt="";
stt = '#' + String(current);
var fin= $(stt);
fin.append('<div id="current01"></div>');
document.getElementById(current).style.width="40%";
```

Unable to create the division with the name ("current" + c) . In the style statement it says

```
document.getElementById(current) is null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var current = "current" + String(c)
$('<div id="'+current+'"> </div>').appendTo('body');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Andrew!!! That saved a lot of time. If you know any good reference for learning jquery faster please let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

I think every attribute must to be between double quotes (`"`), so perhaps you need to do:

`$('<div id="'+current+'" > </div>').appendTo('body');`

Comment: That'll create a div with the name "current" and not ("current" + c)

Comment: you're right, my bad... didnt understand your question at first... i edited

Answer (score 0):

you have to use current as a var while craeting div...like this..

```
var current = "current" + String(c)
$('<div id="'+current+'"> </div>').appendTo('body');
```

Comment: All the three answers are the same now :)